# Why back button doesn't work in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Back button doesn't do anything.
I guess the problem is with `onGenerateRoute`.
I don't have any code that does anything about back button.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/login': (context) => LoginPage(loginFailed: settings.arguments),
          '/main': (context) => MainPage(),
          '/loading': (context) => LoadingPage(credentials: settings.arguments),
          '/addAppointment': (context) => AddAppointmentPage(),
        };

        WidgetBuilder builder = routes[settings.name] ?? routes['/loading'];
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When that happen? After hot restart?

Comment: I forgot exactly when, but it doesn't work when i restart application